# Creating & Managing Users with Facebook/Google/Twitter Sign-In APIs

Tags: api, twitter-oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

i'm implementing the above Sign-In features.

Assuming the user has granted access to the app with Facebook, I want to know the best practices for creating the user an account on our app, and then how best to retrieve that account if they later sign-in using one of the other social networks i.e. is it enough to just pull the account up using the email address supplied by respective API.

This is how I expect the flow to go:

1. User signs in with Facebook
2. Access tokens do not exist in our app, nor does email address supplied by Facebook
3. Create account on app, prompt user to create a password to use with the app (is this necessary?)
4. User returns at a later date, and signs in with Google.
5. Access tokens don't exist in app, but email address does.
6. Pull user account info using email address supplied by Google (Is this acceptable to just use the email address?)
7. Authenticate user on app

Is this generally how the APIs are used? Any other approaches would be welcomed.

Many thanks

Comment: Users may use different email addresses for different services. Google will most likely give you their Google Mail address, but there is no guarantee they used that same address to sign up for Facebook or Twitter. (At least for FB, there is no guarantee you get an email at all, because they can sign up using just their mobile.) So if you find a matching email, you can “join” a new sign-up using a different service to the existing account, but you should provide users with an option to manually say that they already have an account that they just want to add another sign-in option to.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest taking a look at Google Identity Toolkit:
https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/

It is designed to support more authentication providers than just Google and their team has put a lot of thought into many of the issues you raise which is pretty interesting to look through, even if you end up going a different way.